# ParallelTable::nopar: No parallel kernels available; proceeding with sequential evaluation

Tags: warning-messages, parallelization, kernel

I am trying to use a the following code:

```
Total@ParallelTable[If[RegionMember[vuoto, {elettrone[[n, 1]], elettrone[[n, 2]], elettrone[[n, 3]]}],1, 0], {n, Length@elettrone}]
```

to calculate the number of electrons that escape from a surface. Everytime 
I run this code I get the error:

> ParallelTable::nopar: No parallel kernels available; proceeding with
>   sequential evaluation.

In `Evaluation -> Parallel Kernels Configurations...` I have the following settings:

[image]

so it seems that Mma knows I have 4 cores, but won't start parallel kernels.

How do I solve this problem?

I use version 11.3 for Windows.

Comment: Did you try restarting the kernel? If that didn't help, did you try an explicit LaunchKernels? If that didn't help, did you try restarting your computer?

Comment: @mattaiv27 And if nothing helps: Try to perform a clean reinstall of Mathematica. You got also some other weird things going on in your copy of the software, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Szabolcs rebooting the computer did the trick; thanks.

Comment: It is possible that some of your old parallel kernels got "stuck" (didn't exit properly) and used up all available licenses. However, in that case, I would have expected an error message specifically mentioning the license.  Rebooting is a surefire way to get rid of any stuck kernels.